# Windows Shell integration parameters

Tags: windows, shell, context-menu, parameters, integration

I'm trying to integrate a shell menu entry for all files (*) to encrypt them using a tool i already have made.

I have managed to create the entries but I don't really understand how to send the path of the selected file(s) as parameters to my tool.

Also do you think there's a better way than to call my tool with such parameter (i all the code of the encryption tool)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Windows Registry

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Encrypt My Files]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Encrypt My Files\command]

@="mytool.exe -enc %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Decrypt My Files]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Decrypt My Files\command]

@="mytool.exe -dec %1"

ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256986

Comment: Yes, I managed to do it by self but I couldn't add an answer since I had too little rep :P Great answear nevertheless!